# Spring transaction management using JdbcTemplate and AmazonS3

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions

In a spring boot project I have created a service that is called `UpdateClientImage`, this service contains an `update(String clientId, String imageUrl)` method, inside of this method are being called these other methods, the `clientImageDAO.update(clientID, imageUrl)` and the `imageFileAdapter.delete(previousImageUrl)` methods.

Internally the `clientImageDAO.update(clientID, imageUrl)` method is using `JdbcTemplate` to update the new `imageUrl` in an Oracle database, and the `imageFileAdapter.delete(previousImageUrl)` method is using `AmazonS3` to delete the image from Amazon S3.

This is an example of how the `UpdateClientImage` service looks:

```java
@Service
public class UpdateClientImage {
    @Autowired
    private ClientImageDAO clientImageDAO;

    @Autowired
    private ImageFileAdapter imageFileAdapter;

    @Override
    public void update(String clientId, String imageUrl) {
        // Perform in the oracle database the update operation using clientImageDAO
        clientImageDAO.update(clientId, imageUrl);

        // Delete from Amazon S3 the previous image using imageFileAdapter
        String previousImageUrl = /* Retrieve previous image URL */;
        imageFileAdapter.delete(previousImageUrl);
    }
}
```

What I would like to achieve is that when the `imageFileAdapter.delete(previousImageUrl)` method fails then the `clientImageDAO.update(clientID, imageUrl)` method is rolled back.

Would be some way to achieve this? Maybe by using spring AOP, or Java Transaction API (JTA), or some other alternative?

I am not sure what would be the best way to approach this type of transaction management when using these different data sources.

Thanks in advance.